# Angular JS promise not returning value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am new to Angular JS and I tried to load this JS in one of the files (cshtml extension), it did alert the message 'testing 1' but it did not alert 'testing 2'. Can I know whats the issue here. Your kind guidance would be a great help to me. From what I understand is that when the page loads, it will run the $q.all correct ? But somehow, it's not working

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
alert("Testing 1");
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $q, $http,$timeout) {
   
    function doTask1() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve("Testing 2");
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    console.log("ListController instantiated");
    $q.all([
        doTask1(),
        
    ]).then(function (value) {
        
        alert(value);
    });
    
});
```

Inside the cshtml file, (All of the angular dependencies files are in the "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" ), there is no error in the console log hence I knew that Angular has successfully been imported in

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div ng-controller="ListController as listCtrl" class="margin-top-80px">

</div>

@section Scripts{

    <script src="~/Scripts/controllers/News/ListController.js"></script>
}
```

[This is the output. It alerts the message "testing 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm8mY.png)

[But the console log is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwIsp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely cause is that the controller is not being instantiated. For debugging purposes, include a console log to indicate instantiation of the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
alert("testing 1");
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $q, $http,$timeout) {
   
    function doTask1() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve("testing 2");
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    //**********DEBUGGING
    console.log("ListController instantiated");

    $q.all([
        doTask1(),
        
    ]).then(function (value) {
        
        alert(value);
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Thanks for all the help!

Instead of

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

I changed it to

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

and
Instead of

```
<div ng-controller="ListController as listCtrl" class="margin-top-80px">
</div>
```

try adding "ng-app"

```
<div ng-app="myApp ng-controller="ListController as listCtrl" class="margin-top-80px">
</div>
```